# sscanf ignores the first of two consecutive strings. I need the appropriate format string

Tags: c, scanf

The first line of the output is the input string given to the sscanf command shown below

and the other lines are just printed values of scanned values with arg1 and arg2 being the high and low byte of the args uint16_t argument respectively.

I don't understand why id01 isn't scanned and assigned to packet.identifier.

I need a working format string that can get both id01 and switch.
Also, an explanation on format strings is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct data_packet{
   char identifier[8];
   char command[8];
   uint8_t arg1;
   uint8_t arg2;
};

#define INPUT_STR "<<< id01 switch 0xAB29 >>>"
struct data_packet parse_input(char *input){
    //uint8_t exit_code = 1;
    struct data_packet packet;
    uint8_t conversions = 0;
    uint16_t args = 0;
    conversions = sscanf(input , "<<< %s %s %x >>>", packet.identifier, packet.command, &args);
    packet.arg1 = (args >> 8); // High Byte of args
    packet.arg2 = (args & 0x00FF); //Low byte of args
    //if (conversions == 3) exit_code = 0;
    //return exit_code;
    return packet;
}

int main(void){
    
    struct data_packet data = parse_input(INPUT_STR);
    printf("%s\n", INPUT_STR);
    printf("identifier: %s\ncommand: %s\narg1: 0x%0x\narg2: 0x%0x\n", data.identifier, data.command, data.arg1, data.arg2);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve], and how to [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Please post the complete code - a screenshot of a single line doesn't help.

Comment: And please post the code as text not as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting code `%x` is for `unsigned int`, not `uint16_t`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

For `uint16_t` use the pre-defined macro `SCNx16` from the `<inttypes.h>` header:

```
sscanf(input , "<<< %s %s %" SCNx16 " >>>", packet.identifier, packet.command, &args);
```

---

What's probably is happening is that because `unsigned int` is typically 32 bits, the `sscanf` function will write half of those 32 bits into one of your other variables. Quite probably `packet.identifier[0]`, which is set to a zero which happens to be the same as the string terminator.

If you used a debugger to look into the actual contents of `package.identifier` you would probably have seen this very quickly.

And also take this as a lesson to *always* build with extra warnings enabled, and treat them as errors that *must* be fixed.

Comment: sscanf(input , "<<< %s %s %" SCNx16 " >>>", packet.identifier, packet.command, &args);

Comment: @AmirrezaFiroozi Ah yes, I forgot that `%`. :) Added to answer

Answer (score 1):

Running the code through an [online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/FG3E5AFr7) I see the warning:

```
main.c:17:46: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’,
but argument 5 has type ‘uint16_t * {aka short unsigned int *}’ [-Wformat=]
 conversions = sscanf(input , "<<< %s %s %x >>>", packet.identifier, packet.command, &args);
                                          ^
```

Change the declaration to:

```
uint32_t args = 0;
```

And it runs cleanly.